# Citing multiple publications by same author in same year in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, citations

I have two citations by the same author, and they were published in the same year.

Right now, my code looks like this

```
blah blah Hansen [-@Hansen2015a; -@Hansen2015b]
```

and I get this

```
blah blah Author (2015; 2015) blah blah
```

I want the result to look like this

```
blah blah Author (2015a, 2015b) blah blah
```

In my case, I want to cite both publications in the same sentence, but I also want to know how to achieve this lettering if I were to cite these publications in different sentences.

I tried editing the year in the BibTeX citation entry to manually insert the `a` and `b`, but that results in this

```
blah blah Author (n.d.; n.d.) blah blah
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi mdawgig and welcome to Stack Overflow!
Here are two examples of what the entries (same author, same year) in BibTeX file (`.bib`) might look like:

```
@article{Author_2015a,
    Author = {Author, A. and Another, B.},
    Journal = {Amazing Journal},
    Pages = {50-100},
    Title = {A New Paper},
    Volume = {5},
    Year = {2015}
}

@article{Author_2015b,
    Author = {Author, A. and Another, C.},
    Journal = {Another Amazing Journal},
    Pages = {100-150},
    Title = {Another New Paper},
    Volume = {7},
    Year = {2015}
}
```

In R Markdown document, a line like this:

```
# using minus ( - ) sign before the @ will suppress author's name  
blah blah Author [-@Author_2015a; -@Author_2015b] blah blah
```

should return desired result (citing both publications in the same sentence):

```
blah blah Author (2015a, 2015b) blah blah
```

> I also want to know how to achieve this lettering if I were to cite
>   these publications in different sentences.

There are many R Markdown resources out there. You may find some of these useful ([Bibliographies and Citations](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html), [Bibliographies](https://monashdatafluency.github.io/r-rep-res/bibliographies.html), [Bibliographies and citations](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html), [Citations](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/citations.html)).

Let us know if this answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my .bib file and R Markdown references look like that as far as I can tell, but the error persists. Both .bib are like:

`@Article{Hansen2015a,
  author  = {Hansen, Gretchen and Carpenter, Stephen and Gaeta, Jereme and Hennessy, Joseph and Vander Zanden, Jake},
  journal = {Canadian Journal of Fisheries and Aquatic Sciences},
  title   = {Predicting walleye recruitment as a tool for prioritizing management actions},
  year    = {2015},
  pages   = {661-672},
  volume  = {72},
}`

In-text: `in Hansen et al. [-@Hansen2015a; -@Hansen2015b]`

Comment: I can perfectly reproduce your citations. As far as i know, Pandoc generates citations in R Markdown documents. Do you have Rstudio updated (also, `rmarkdown` and `knitr` packages)?

Comment: My `rmarkdown` and `knitr` were up to date, but I did update Rstudio to no avail. The output remains `Hansen et al. (2015; 2015)`.

Comment: Did you try installing RStudio [Preview](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/)? It will automatically includes/download latest Pandoc version.

Comment: I updated to Preview and the citations are the same.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you have both references: `@Article{Hansen2015a, ... }` and `@Article{Hansen2015b, ... }` in the same `.bib` file with the same `year = {2015}`?

Comment: That is correct. Same file, year is `{2015}` for both.

Comment: It's just an hint... open your `.bib` file with RStudio, then go to menu: `File > Save with Encoding...` and then choose `UTF-8` encoding as default. `Knit` your `.Rmd` file...

Comment: Also, try creating the essential `.Rmd` and minimal `.bib` file (just containing examples above)...

Comment: Well, I think I've identified the source of the problem. 

I had forgotten since I put the citation in that the two papers don't have the _exact_ same set of authors; the second has all the same authors and one additional author. 

Thus, even though they both have the same in-text citation for author (Hansen et al.), they technically do not have the same authors, and thus RMarkdown seems to be acting correctly when it outputs `(2015; 2015)`.

My problem has gone from a technical one to a citation style guide one. Thanks; compiling a minimal `.bib` file is what made me catch on to this.